# How do I change source control when the original TFS server is gone?

Tags: asp.net, tfs

I've got an ASP.NET MVC project I started over a year ago on my home PC. Between then and now my machine died and I had to get a new one. Fortunately I was able to get most of what I needed off of the old one.

Now I'm trying to open the project to do further editing on it, but VS 2015 tells me it can't as the old TFS source control isn't available. (I had used TFS Express on my old machine. Now I'd like to use VSTS.) I checked here on SO and found [Change TFS source control mapping in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316353/change-tfs-source-control-mapping-in-visual-studio-2013), but it seems to assume that the old TFS server is still around. How do I handle it, now that the old machine isn't around?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the source control bindings and edit the project files to completely remove the source control.  Here is a blog post that describes the process:

http://zayko.net/post/How-to-permanently-remove-TFS-Source-Control-association-bindings.aspx

Comment: I'll take a look at this later. Gotta turn in. Thank you!